# How to get Angular Material 5 autocomplete scroll with bounded input?

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, autocomplete, angular-material2

In my Angular app I included an autocomplete component of Angular Material in a Modal. It opens correctly and showing data, but when the page is scrolled the autocomplete listbox stays at a fixed position. It does not 'follow' the input to which is bounded to.

[image]

Online I found a lot of calls of people who are having the same issue, but all without any solution. I tried to include the cdkScrollable to the parent div, but without any success.

Angular version: 5.1.1
Angular Material version: 5.1.1

```
<div class="row" cdkScrollable>
        <form class="example-form">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Select company" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredTestOptions | async" [value]="option">
                        {{ option }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The expected result is as it works on the Angular Material website.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10079. The fix is to make sure your `cdkScrollable` directive is on the root element of the dialog content. But seeing as your version of Angular is old, there may be other problems - a lot of issues have been filed about autocomplete and scrolling.